# trigger a click on multiple elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to trigger a click on multiple elements with the same class but when i do so the first element only get clicked and not the others, frankly I'm trying to make likes to all ask.fm profile answers by using the console of firefox so this is what i did

```
$('.like').trigger('click');
```

but i realized that only the first element (answer) get clicked so i did something else

```
$('.like').each(function(){$(this).trigger('click');})
```

but the problem still exist, os what am i doing wrong here !!

Edit: The html code

all answers got this element in it

```
<a class="like hintable" hint="Like" href="#" onclick="Like.quickLike(128332156539, &quot;mo7am_rs&quot;, &quot;/likes/am77r/question/128332156539/add&quot;); return false;" style="display:block"></a>
```

and i want to click this element in all answers element

Comment: add your html code here. it might help us too

Comment: `trigger`  executes all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements, or in other words all elements with that class, so the issue isn't `trigger`, it's you, obviously!

Comment: Also add your `.like` click handler code

Comment: Show the function you are triggering from `$('.like')` elements ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Frankly I'm trying to make likes to all ask.fm profile answers

Your code should work, so, probably they're ignoring/blocking two too consecutive clicks to prevent bots and missclicks.

A workaround to this would be adding a **sleep** to it (*you should **adjust the sleep value**, because it depends on their secret configured threshold*).

The following code would try a click after each 10 seconds:

```
var sleep = 0;
$('.like').each(function(){
    var likeElement = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        likeElement.trigger('click');
    }, sleep);
    sleep += 10000;
});
```

Please, also verify if that practice is compliant to the site's policy.

Comment: i forgot to mention that i did  try to delay the clicking procedure and it didn't work neither your code did :(

Comment: @MOHAMMADRASIM Try it with a larger sleep. Eg. 10000 (10 seconds, see updated answer). Or another even larger, eg. 100000 (100 seconds. - as I said: you should adjust the sleep value, because it will depend on their secret configured threshold)

Comment: I've increased the timeout in your code but  your code doesn't even click the first element

Comment: @MOHAMMADRASIM You're right. Please, see my updated code. I've fixed a closure issue. It should work now :) Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : write a click handler for all like element and then trigger click event on it.

```
$(function(){
  //register a handler
  $( ".like" ).on( "click", function() {
   alert( $( this ).text() );
  });
  //trigger click 
  $( ".like" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z5ru1xzz/1/)**

Comment: ok, your code works but i have to click an alert box each time and that's not what i wanted to do, i wanted the code to click the elements without the intervention of the user

Comment: I kept the alert box to show that every div is getting clicked by showing its text, you can remove that and put your logic.